# How to get request.route_url to spit out an https link instead of http using pyramid?

Tags: python, https, pyramid

I have an app on the `pyramid` framework, and I'm calling `request.route_url` everywhere. I just switched my app over to HTTPS, and all of the links are still coming out as HTTP.

Is there a global setting I can put in a config file somewhere that will change this for my whole app, or alternately is there an argument I can pass to this function that will give me either an HTTPS URL or preferably a // agnostic URL (//)?

Answer (score 7):

Your WSGI server is misconfigured if it is not telling the application that the incoming url is HTTPS. This is almost always because you're behind a reverse proxy (like nginx) which is talking to the WSGI server using HTTP and not properly communicating to the WSGI server that the **original** request was HTTPS.

**IF** everything is configured properly with nginx / waitress / gunicorn / ... etc (your proxy and your wsgi server) then `request.route_url` will emit the correct URLs. The fix is not within Pyramid itself.

Here is some documentation on the issue. Some of the solutions here are specific to waitress, but some of them are more general (the prefix middleware) and will work everywhere. Gunicorn and other WSGI servers also have their own specific ways of handling this if you aren't using waitress.

https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/waitress/en/latest/reverse-proxy.html

Comment: Hm, that's troubling, because I don't really know what's going on in front of my application.  It's running on Heroku.  I'm absolutely sure there's no Nginx involved and I am sure that waitress is running, but I don't know what WSGI is doing.  Also not sure what I could possibly change to fix the issue.

Comment: In that case heroku is acting as a proxy. From my link above it should be clear what's going on - you need **something** in your stack that sets `environ['wsgi.url_scheme'] = 'https'` appropriately. There are quite a few ways to accomplish that. For example, if you're positive that every request is over ssl then just set `url_scheme = https` in your `[server:main]` section of your ini file.

Comment: I disagree a bit that the fix should not be in Pyramid itself. If you use AWS ALB for example it is impossible to add extra headers that can be used to tell Pyramid that the client is using HTTPS. I end up adding a WSGI middleware to force the wsgi.url_scheme for those deployments, but having to do that is a bit annoying.

Answer (score 2):

What you want is `route_path`, it returns URLs starting with `/`, with no scheme, domain and port (a path).

http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/api/request.html#pyramid.request.Request.route_path

Comment: This will solve the exact question asked but it is hiding the problem which itself can manifest itself in many different ways other than simply url generation (like how cookies are set, how security is checked, etc).

Comment: Thanks for the precision @MichaelMerickel, up-voting your answer.